# JavaScript: Calculate Jitter and Packet Loss

Tags: javascript, packet-loss, jitter

Is there a way to calculate `Jitter` and `Packet Loss` using JavaScript?

If there is no way to do that (and we have `Latency`), is there a way to calculate `Jitter` and `Packet Loss` with `Latency` (Ping Time)? If yes, what is the formula?

Comment: In the browser on the clientside? In Node you'd probably have some access to the network traffic, but I think you're going to have to be more specific ?

Comment: No, it's not that specific. I want a roughly solution.

Comment: Then there is no such solution. There's no magic function that works both clientside and serverside that has access to the network traffic in such detail

Comment: Is there a way to Ping using JavaScript, then calculate the Packet Loss and Jitter from those Ping results?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Yes @W.M. But unfortunately it's an old project and I don't have the code. You should start from Ping with JS and then calculate it. It was not that hard to achieve the formula. Maybe this links help you: https://github.com/jdfreder/pingjs and http://support.esi-estech.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/44/18/ping-latency-jitter-and-packet-loss